# Pie chart keeps adjusting itself when updating - D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, pie-chart

I'm having a bit of a problem.

I'm using D3 to make a pie chart for an application I'm building. I basically it have it working, but I'm annoyed by one aspect of the chart. I've adapted the chart from here: http://jsfiddle.net/vfkSs/1/ to work with my application.

The data is passed in here:

```
data = data ? data : { "slice1": Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1), 
                       "slice2": Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1), 
                       "slice3": Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1), 
                       "slice4": Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1) };
```

But somewhere in this file these slices are being ordered by value, which is not what I want.

The issue with this chart is that when it updates it adjusts all pieces of the chart to keep them in ascending order. For example the largest portion of the pie is always on the right, and smallest on the left. I would like these to remain in the order they are when the data is passed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is buried a bit in the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Pie-Layout#sort).

> pie.sort([comparator])
>
> If comparator is specified, sets the sort order of data for the layout
>   using the specified comparator function. **Pass null to disable sorting**.

(bolding mine)

So, modify your `.pie` call to:

```
var cv_pie = d3.layout.pie().sort(null).value(function (d) { return d.value });
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vfkSs/27/).